# How to initialize the IEnumerable<CustomModel> in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

.NET application. I have these classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public string BrandDescription { get; set; }
    public string StyleNumber { get; set; }

    public FamilyTree FamilyTree { get; set; }
    public DssProduct DssProduct { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<OptionData> Options { get; set; }
}

public class OptionData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Colour PrimaryColour { get; set; }
    public Colour SecondaryColour { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SizeData> Sizes { get; set; }
}

public class Colour
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to add some sample data to this model as below.

```
return new ProductMessageEvents()
        {
          Metadata = new KafkaProductEvent.Metadata
          {
            Timestamp = "test",
            Environment = "test"
          },
          Product = new KafkaProductEvent.Product
          {
            AgeGrading = "test",
            KeycodeType = "type1",
            FamilyTree = new KafkaProductEvent.FamilyTree
            {
              Class = new KafkaProductEvent.CodeNamePair
              {
                Code = "test code",
                Name = "test name"
              }
            },
            DssProduct = new KafkaProductEvent.DssProduct
            {
              DocumentStatus = "active"
            }
          },
          Version = "latestVersion"
        };
```

I tried as below.

```
Options = new OptionData[]
    {
      new OptionData
      {
        PrimaryColour = new Colour
        {
          Name = "White"
        }
      },
      new OptionData
      {
        PrimaryColour = new Colour
        {
          Name = "Green"
        }
      }
    }
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly Convert type ProductEvents.OptionData[] to  IList

In the above code, I am not sure how to add data to Options. Can someone help me to 
add data to IEnumerable of Option field? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Create a `List<OptionData>`, add required value and assign to `Options` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, like a `List<T>` or an array:

```
DssProduct = new KafkaProductEvent.DssProduct
{
  DocumentStatus = "active"
},
Options = new OptionData[]
{ new OptionData // fist option
    { Id = Guid.NewGuid()
    }
, new OptionData // second option
    { Id = Guid.NewGuid()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I added as you answered. But I started getting error. I have updated my code above. May I know how to do it correctly?

Comment: Not sure. I guess the error is somewhere else, since this code works: http://www.ideone.com/FWcipb.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<T>` is just an generic interface. You can initiazlize such field with any concrete class that implements the interface.

Most common is `List<T>`, so you can use it to initialize your field.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `new List<OptionData>` either in initialisation or create a variable and use that.

```
return new ProductMessageEvents()
{
    Metadata = new KafkaProductEvent.Metadata
    {
        Timestamp = "test",
        Environment = "test"
    },
    Product = new KafkaProductEvent.Product
    {
        AgeGrading = "test",
        KeycodeType = "type1",
        FamilyTree = new KafkaProductEvent.FamilyTree
        {
            Class = new KafkaProductEvent.CodeNamePair
            {
                Code = "test code",
                Name = "test name"
            }
        },
        DssProduct = new KafkaProductEvent.DssProduct
        {
            DocumentStatus = "active"
        },
        Options = new List<OptionData>
        {
            //Add all items here.
        }
      },
      Version = "latestVersion"
    };
```